# ¿Cómo leer email entrante y descargar los ficheros adjuntos? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, email

Buenas a todos y a todas.

Necesito consejo experto. Estoy investigando técnicas que me permitan poder recoger emails entrantes y descargar los ficheros que tienen adjuntos en PHP.

Tendré un formulario en el cual el usuario adjunta varios archivos. Ese formulario, va a enviar un mail a una dirección de la empresa.

Mi programa, debe ser capaz de:

- Entrar en la dirección mail de la empresa.
- Tener una especie de "listener" que avise cuándo hay un correo nuevo. ¿Se puede hacer?
- Cuando llega el correo nuevo, abrirlo y descargar todos los ficheros adjuntos (usando una clase por ejemplo).

En mi proyecto no estoy usando framework y programo el backend en PHP.

¿Hay alguna alternativa, sin usar framework, para poder realizar la tarea?
¿Hay alguna alternativa, aunque sea más compleja, usando un framework?
¿Cómo me entero que ha llegado un email nuevo a esa bandeja de manera asíncrona?

He buscado por internet y sé que hay clases que pueden entrar a una dirección de email, a una bandeja y obtener los mails.

Mil gracias a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtener los mensajes es fácil, para ello podemos usar la [extensión IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) de php:

```js
$server = '127.0.0.1';
$usr = 'xxx';
$pwd = 'xxx';
$inbox = array();

$connection = imap_open("{$server/notls}", $user, $pwd);

$num_msg = imap_num_msg($connection);

for($i = 1; $i <= $num_msg; $i++) {
    $inbox[] = array(
      'index'     => $i,
      'header'    => imap_headerinfo($connection, $i),
      'body'      => imap_body($connection, $i),
      'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($connection, $i)
    );
}
```

Y para extraer los adjuntos [aquí tienes un excelente ejemplo de código](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/extract-attachments-email-php-imap/) que te será muy fácil de implementar.

Comment: ¿La extensión nativa se "entera" cuando un mensaje nuevo ha llegado? o, por el contrario ¿enviaría algún mensaje por parámetros usando POST al documento php mail de alguna manera?

Comment: No, no se entera, para automatizarlo tienes varias opciones, una es meter lo que hay justo debajo de imap_open en un while(true) (con un sleep de unos segundos entre loop y loop) y llamarlo con nohup: "nohup php myscript.php &"... pero sinceramente yo pondría el script tal cual en cron

Comment: Interesante... A ver si hay alguien que sepa alguna solución asíncrona para que se entere que llegan nuevos mails. Gracias!